# SQL Join get end date on the right table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like this.. I want to get every user with their one last transaction,

`tb_user`

```
---------------------
userID  |   Name
---------------------
1       |   Alex
2       |   Jack
---------------------
```

and `tb_transaction`

```
-------------------------------------
ID  |   userId    |  lastTransaction
-------------------------------------
1   |   1         |  2017-10-10
2   |   1         |  2017-10-11
4   |   2         |  2017-10-8
5   |   2         |  2017-10-15
-------------------------------------
```

I want to get something like this:

```
Alex -> 2017-10-11  
Jack -> 2017-10-15
```

My sql code is:

```
select * 
from 
tb_user 
inner join 
(select userID,lastTransaction from tb_transaction order by lastTransaction) as 
x on x.userID = tb_user.userID
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT A.USERID, MAX(B.LASTTRANSACTION) AS LAST_TXN_DATE
FROM
TB_USER A 
LEFT JOIN 
TB_TRANSACTION B
ON A.USERID = B.USERID
GROUP BY A.USERID;
```

This will give the last transaction date for every user.

Comment: Work perfectly!!  Thanks!!